# Error while passing secret variables to Azure DevOps Release pipeline through REST API

Tags: azure, rest, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Iam triggering a release pipeline in Azure DevOps using REST API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#configurationvariablevalue

Iam trying to pass a variable as secret by passing "isSecret" to true along with "value" in the request body. But I get the following error before the release pipeline is triggered.

Error code: 400 - Bad Request

Error Message: The 'secret' property of variables cannot be altered while creating a deployment. Verify the value provided for variables 'name of the variable' at scope 'name of the stage' and try again.

Any help on how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried to reproduce it in my environment and got the below results.**

Make sure you have declared that variable in Azure release pipeline variables as a secret and enable Settable at Release time as shown below

[image]

[image]

Now define the variable in the rest api body as below.

```
{
    "definitionId": 1,
    "description": "New release triggered via API",
    "isDraft": false,
    "reason": "none",
    "manualEnvironments": null,
     .
     .
     . 
    "variables": {
        "variable1": {
            "value": "testsecretvalue",
            "isSecret": true
    }
  }
```

After making the above changes, when you send the api request below is the output.

[image]